# Determine a certain date is full of events in fullcalendar

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I created a fullcalendar with minTime and MaxTime. And i filled it with events without overlapping. How can i determine if that certain day is full of events from mintime to maxtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can just order the events by their minTime and check if their endTime equals the minTime of the next event. This should run in O(n*log(n)).